# How can Haystack SearchQuerySet filter by unrelated table?

Tags: django, django-haystack

I'm trying to filter SearchQuerySet against a User-object-permissions table to limit results based on the current user's permissions.

This model maps user to a generic object:

```
class UserObjectPermission(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id') 

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

I try to filter the results inside the view (obv won't work):

```
query = SearchQuerySet()
user_allowed_objects = (UserObjectPermission
                        .filter(user__pk=request.user.pk)
                        .values_list('content_type', 'object_id')
query = query.filter(#some pair lookup vs_user_allowed_objects)
```

Would a raw SQL join be possible here?

Comment: Could you post your `search_indexes.py` please, along with your User Model?

Comment: User model is default, search index just has name/description. The process is being designed, the above is just starting out